# Как реализовать экспорт виртуальной машины со всеми снимками

Tags: virtualbox, виртуализация, виртуальная-машина

Как осуществить перенос виртуальной машины (например по `SFTP`) с компьютера А на компьютер Б со всеми многочисленными снимками. `VirtualBox` не поддерживает данную операцию и при экспорте / импорте в формате `.ova` все снимки пропадают и на них нельзя откатиться. Может быть все таки есть какие-то решения? Я пытался вырезать папку машины из `VirtualBox\ VMs/machine` и вставить на другом ПК в `VirtualBox\ VMs/` но `VirtualBox` не отображает эту машину, в чем может быть проблема? Я понимаю что есть файлы `.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` и подобные, в которых должна присутствовать запись `uuid` машины, я писал туда подобное:

```
<MachineEntry uuid="{3582205f-b078-44be-93de-15559fbb8ad0}" src="~/VirtualBox VMs/machine/machine.vbox"/>
```

Перезагружаю `VirtualBox`, захожу и безрезультатно, машина не отображается, кто нибудь встречался с данной проблемой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Увы, в [документации](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf)(и [VBoxManage тоже](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-export)) нет ничего про снапшоты машины. Так же, на английской версии sof [был аналогичный вопрос](https://superuser.com/q/1184529) из чего можно сделать вывод, что их копирование подразумевает копирование машины целиком.

А для того что бы машина добавилась - в верхнем меню `Machine > Add...` и указываем `.vbox`(или `.xml`, зависит от версии) из скопированной папки

Answer (score 2):

Немного добавлю от себя к чему пришел. Папки машин занимают довольно много места (со всеми снимками) в моем случае около `8-10ГБ`, для переноса на `FTP` лучше класть их в архивы и сжимать, у меня получилось сжать машины где-то до `3ГБ`, что слегка упрощает передачу машин на `FTP`. На компьютере Б необходимо скачать все архивы (можно `wget`) и разархивировать их в папку `VirtualBox VMs` и для того чтобы `VirtualBox` отобразил новые машины не нужно править его конфиги, он сам сделает запись в них после `vboxmanage registervm <machine>` ну или через графику как описали выше `Machine > Add...`, теперь этот процесс довольно просто автоматизировать когда понятна суть